# Tensorflow model with error `ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 500) are incompatible`

Tags: tensorflow

I've attempted to build a simple multi-input, single-output model with LSTM layers. Generated some data to fit too. Basically, I've got a reference corpus each length 100, and a question corpus, each doc of length 25, and some answer where the length is 5.

```
TEXT_VOCAB_SIZE, QUESTION_VOCAB_SIZE = 10000, 25
ANSWER_VOCAB_SIZE = 500

max_samples, max_length, max_qn_length = 1000, 100, 25
max_ans_length = 5

text_corpus = np.random.randint(1, TEXT_VOCAB_SIZE,
                               size=(max_samples, max_length))
questions_corpus = np.random.randint(1, QUESTION_VOCAB_SIZE,
                               size=(max_samples, max_qn_length))
answers_corpus = np.random.randint(1,ANSWER_VOCAB_SIZE,
                                  size=(max_samples, max_ans_length))

backend.clear_session()
m31_corpus_input = Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype='int32')
m31_qn_input = Input(shape=(max_qn_length,), dtype='int32')

m31_corpus_emb = layers.Embedding(64, TEXT_VOCAB_SIZE)(m31_corpus_input)
m31_qn_emb = layers.Embedding(64, QUESTION_VOCAB_SIZE)(m31_qn_input)

m31_corpus_lstm = layers.LSTM(32)(m31_corpus_emb)
m31_qn_lstm = layers.LSTM(32)(m31_qn_emb)

m31_concat = layers.concatenate([m31_corpus_lstm, m31_qn_lstm], axis=-1)
# m31_concat = layers.Concatenate()([m31_corpus_lstm, m31_qn_lstm])
m31_ans = layers.Dense(ANSWER_VOCAB_SIZE, activation='softmax')(m31_concat)
m31 = models.Model(inputs=[m31_corpus_input, m31_qn_input], outputs=m31_ans)
print(m31.summary())

m31.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['acc'])

m31.fit([text_corpus, questions_corpus], 
        answers_corpus, epochs=10, batch_size=64,
       validation_split=0.2)
```

When running the code i got the following error

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 500) are incompatible
```

Been tweaking the different values in this model but still cannot get the answer to why this is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it:

```
TEXT_VOCAB_SIZE, QUESTION_VOCAB_SIZE, ANSWER_VOCAB_SIZE = 10000, 25, 500
max_length, max_qn_length, max_ans_length = 100, 25, 5
max_samples = 1000


text_corpus = np.random.randint(1, TEXT_VOCAB_SIZE,
                               size=(max_samples, max_length))
questions_corpus = np.random.randint(1, QUESTION_VOCAB_SIZE,
                               size=(max_samples, max_qn_length))
answers_corpus = np.random.randint(0,ANSWER_VOCAB_SIZE,
                                  size=(max_samples,))
answers_corpus = to_categorical(answers_corpus)


backend.clear_session()
m31_corpus_input = Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype='int32')
m31_qn_input = Input(shape=(max_qn_length,), dtype='int32')

m31_corpus_emb = layers.Embedding(TEXT_VOCAB_SIZE, 64)(m31_corpus_input)
m31_qn_emb = layers.Embedding(QUESTION_VOCAB_SIZE, 64)(m31_qn_input)

m31_corpus_lstm = layers.LSTM(32)(m31_corpus_emb)
m31_qn_lstm = layers.LSTM(32)(m31_qn_emb)

m31_concat = layers.Concatenate()([m31_corpus_lstm, m31_qn_lstm])
m31_ans = layers.Dense(ANSWER_VOCAB_SIZE, activation='softmax')(m31_concat)
m31 = models.Model(inputs=[m31_corpus_input, m31_qn_input], outputs=m31_ans)
print(m31.summary())


m31.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['acc'])

m31.fit([text_corpus, questions_corpus], answers_corpus, 
        epochs=10, batch_size=128)
```